# Create dynamic html table of dates using Razor Page Partial

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages, partial-views

I'm developing a .NET Core 3.1 Razor Page Application.

**Request**

I need to create a page that allows a user to select a date, add X amount of days to that date and then generate a table comprising of those dates with the ability to add a value against each date.

**Approach**

I have a page that allows the user to select a start date (using a Date Picker) and a number (from a drop-down list) that represents the total number of days to add to the start date.

[image]

Once the user hits the Set button, a JQuery and Ajax (GET) call is made to a Get Handler in my Page Model:

**JQuery/ Ajax**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    //alert("Ready!");

    $("#load").click(function () {
        //alert("button");
        var startDate = $("#StartDate").val();
        var duration = $('#Duration').val();
        var turl = '/SPC/Index?handler=CarPartial&StartDate=' + startDate + '&Duration=' + duration;        
            $('#spc_data_table').load(turl);
        
    });

});
```

**CSHTML**

```
<div class="row">
 <div id="spc_data_table" class="col-md-12">


 </div>
</div>
```

**Page Model**

```
[BindProperty]
public IList<SpcTable> data { get; set; }

public class SpcTable
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string tableDate { get; set; }
    public string tableValue { get; set; }
}

public PartialViewResult OnGetCarPartial(string StartDate, string Duration)
    {
        data = new List<SpcTable>();
        var EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(Duration) - 1);
        int count = 0;

        for (var date = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate); date <= EndDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            data.Add(new SpcTable { id = count, tableDate = date.ToShortDateString(), tableValue = null });
            count++;
        }

        return Partial("_SpcTable", data);
    }
```

**Partial**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submit').on('click', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.post('', $('form').serialize(), function () {
            alert('Posted using jQuery');
        });
    });

});
```

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="data.Index" value="@item.id" />
                <input type="hidden" name="data[@item.id].id" value="@item.id" />
                @item.id
            </td>
            <td><input name="data[@item.id].tableDate" value="@item.tableDate" class="form-control form-control-sm" readonly/></td>
            <td><input name="data[@item.id].tableValue" value="@item.tableValue" class="form-control form-control-sm" /></td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>

<div class="form-group row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

A partial page is then returned in the form of a HTML table and it will contain a row for every date. The user then adds a value beside each date and then submits the form via another JQuery/ Ajax call (POST)

[image]

This works, however, if the user wants to increase or decrease the number of days in the table, they select a different number from the drop down list and reload the partial, however, all of the initial values they would have input against the initial dates within the table are lost.

**My Questions**

1. Is there a better approach to creating my request?
2. If not, is there a way I can keep the table values in the partial even if it is reloaded?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @tcode, what is your `#load` and `#spc_data_table`? Also what is your partial view like? It seems you want to keep Value you set for the date when the partial reload, right? I think it cannot say to keep but to pass the value to backend and post back to the partial.

Comment: @Rena Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question and added the `CSHTML` Page which shows the `spc_data_table` and the Partial as well `_SpcTable`. You are correct, I do want to keep the values set for the dates when the partial reloads. Would you know how to do this by posting to the backend and then posting back to the UI again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `tableValue` for `tableDate`, you can add an `onchange` event to monitor if the `tableValue` changed or not. Then add the value to list and pass it to backend as a json string. In backend, you can deserialize this json and compare with new `tableDate`, add the value to the existing `tableDate`.

Here is a working demo:

View:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form>
    <input id="StartDate" type="date" />
    <select id="Duration">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="load" value="set" />
    <div class="row">
        <div id="spc_data_table" class="col-md-12">
   
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS in View:

```
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    var obj = {};
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#load").click(function () {
            var startDate = $("#StartDate").val();
            var duration = $('#Duration').val();
            var turl = '?handler=CarPartial&StartDate=' + startDate + '&Duration=' + duration;
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(obj)) {
                $('#spc_data_table').load(turl);
            }
            else {
                turl = turl + "&json=" + JSON.stringify(obj);
                $('#spc_data_table').load(turl);
                obj = {};   
            }
        });

    });
    function saveValue(objectValue) {
        var value = objectValue.value;
        var keyName = $(objectValue).closest("td").prev("td").find("input").val()
        obj[keyName] = value;
    }
</script>
}
```

Partial View:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>  
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="data.Index" value="@item.id" />
                <input type="hidden" name="data[@item.id].id" value="@item.id" />
                @item.id
            </td>
            <td><input name="data[@item.id].tableDate" value="@item.tableDate" class="form-control form-control-sm" readonly /></td> 
                         //add this event....
            <td><input onchange="saveValue(this);" name="data[@item.id].tableValue" value="@item.tableValue" class="form-control form-control-sm" /></td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {

        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public IList<SpcTable> data { get; set; }

    public class SpcTable
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string tableDate { get; set; }
        public string tableValue { get; set; }
    }
    public PartialViewResult OnGetCarPartial(string StartDate, string Duration, string json)
    {

        data = new List<SpcTable>();
        var EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(Duration) - 1);
        int count = 0;

        for (var date = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate); date <= EndDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            data.Add(new SpcTable { id = count, tableDate = date.ToShortDateString(), tableValue = null });
            count++;
        }
        //judge if the set tableValue for tableDate in frontend
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
        {
            //deserialize to the model
            var model = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                foreach (var date in data)
                {
                    //if you set value for tableDate
                    //and the tableDate still exist after filtering
                    if (item.Key == date.tableDate)
                    {
                        //set the value for this tableDate
                        date.tableValue = item.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Partial("_SpcTable", data);
    }

}
```

**Note:**

The onchange event will trigger if you did a second operation. That is to say, when you fill an input, you need choose a select or fill another input or click the white space of the page to trigger the onclick event.

Comment: Wow. This is way above the call of duty, but I am very thankful. Thank you so much for the time you have spent on your answer to my question. It will help me tremendously. Stack Overflow can be a bit elitist at times, but the more Renas the better it becomes :)

Comment: Glad it can help you. :)